# Defined Operation Question

Tags: boolean-algebra

On my previous exam I was given 2 multiple choice questions.

```
 Define the operation → as:

 A → B = ~A + B. Then, A → (A → A) = ?

 With the correct answer being '1'
```

Then the next question

```
 Define the operation → as:

 A → B = ~A + B. Then, (A → A) → A = ?

 With the correct answer being 'A'
```

That is the entire text of the question. Nothing that looks like this is in the material he provided us, nor is it in any of the homeworks, nor is it in any of my personal notes.

What is this notation supposed to represent? What is it called?

Comment: It is a definition. When you define something, you say "Let blah be such and such", while "blah" is a new thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to substitute the right hand side (I will explain only the first example): (A -> A) right hand is substituted as ~A+A which is 1. Then the remaining A->1 is substituted as ~A+1 which is 1. This is the result.

Comment: Thank you, I was ale to learn how to solve this problem.
Its similar to contex free languages that I've seen in CS theory classes.

Answer (score 1):

> What is this notation supposed to represent?

It's a new notation created for this problem. They're using `→` as an arbitrarily chosen new symbol for a new operation that isn't one of the well known operations like AND or NOR.

> What is it called?

It doesn't have a special name. It's just a shorthand for a new operation that was invented by whoever wrote the problem.